# > - operator and "Shape_Area" field in a geodatabase

Tags: python, arcpy

this might be a pure python problem or a problem with arcpy. please help me out:

```
    min_area = float(GKPROZ_functions.min_of_field(out_name,"Shape_Area"))
    print area_max
    if min_area > area_max:
        print "success!"
    else:
        print "failed."            

    if min_area > 100:
        print "success!"
    else:
        print "failed."

    print str(min_area)
```

output:

```
100
failed.
success!
100.018289077
```

min_of_field returns the minimum value of the field "Shape_Area" of the whole feature class. 
it is (apparently) 100.018289077. however if i check that with area_max (supposedly 100) it says it's smaller (failed!). if i check it with 100, it says it's bigger(success!). 
what mistake am i making here? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have provided does not show how `area_max` is assigned a value. When I ran your code, assigning `area_min =  float(100.0182890771)` and `area_max = float(100)` I get a correct output:

```
success!
success!
100.018289077
```

However, If I assign `area_max = str(100)` I am able to replicate the error:

```
failed.
success!
100.018289077
```

It could be that your error is in the assignment of the area_min value but its hard to say for sure without that part of the code.

Comment: this was indeed the problem. i am still unexperienced with python and the ambiguity of types tricked me into thinking everything was ok. thank you for your time!

Comment: You're welcome. It can be tricky to begin with, but you'll soon learn to check for these things.